# Blender Poliigon Addon error when loading textures

Tags: blender

So I just installed the Poliigon material addon to Blender 2.8 Beta, and when I click on the materials folder, it shows all the textures as a picture, not like the sphere that I have selected. Then when I click load material, it gives me an error that I cant decipher. Help is much appreciated.

And since I need at least 10 rep to post images, and blender doesn't let me copy and paste it's errors, I guesss I'll try and summarize the error.

```
Traceback (most recent last call):
   File: "C:\etc...addons\poliigon-material-converter\poliigon)ops_props.py", line 429, in execute conform uv=pmcs.conform_uv
   File: "C:\etc...scripts\modules\ops.py" line 200_call_ret = op_call((self.idname_py(), None, kw)
   Runtime Error: Error: Traceback (most recent last call):
   File: "C:\etc...addons\polligon-material-converter\poliigon_ops_props.py" line 551, in execute status, material = workflow.build_material_from_set(context,set_path)
   File: "C:\etc...addons\polligon-material-converter\poliigon_ops_props.py" line 570, in build_material_from_set self.build_material(contect, files=set_files)
   File "C:\etc...addons\poliigon-mateiral-converter\poliigon_converter.py" line 626, in build_material setattr(node,key,value)
   AttributeError: 'ShaderNodeTextImage' object has no attribute 'color_space'

location C:\etc...Blender 2.8\blender-2.800-git.(a long hexadecimal)-windows64\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py:200\

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Well that was fun to type out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If u still didn't figure it out,  just update the addon and it should work just fine.